# How to make a mutating function in an extension return Int using Swift?

Tags: swift

Why doesn't this code work?

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

extension Int: ExampleProtocol {

    var simpleDescription: String {
        return "The number \(self)"
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        self += 42
    }
}

var x:Int = 7
let y:Int = x.adjust()
```

here is what I get on XCODE

[image]

is there a way to make adjust() return Int without changing its definition in the protocol?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can give adjust a return value. Define it to return an Int in the protocol and class, then have it return itself in the mutating method:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust() -> Int
}
extension Int: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String {
    return "The number \(self)"
    }
    mutating func adjust() -> Int {
        self += 42
        return self
    }
}
var x:Int = 7
let y:Int = x.adjust() //49
```

Comment: I don't want to change the protocol though !

Comment: you don't have to change the protocol, but if you want a return value you'll have to implement the method with a return value. If the implemented method and protocol-defined method don't have the same parameters and return values, it will still work but it won't be considered correctly implementing the protocol

Answer (score 6):

Because the adjust() function does not return value (it just change the value of its instance), you can achieve this by this orders:

```
var x:Int = 7
x.adjust() //adjust x self value
let y:Int = x //assigne x value to y
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ques : *is there a way to make adjust() return Int without changing its definition in the protocol?*

Ans : **No**

The definition/signature of a method tells us what it's going to take as input and what data type it's going to return.

You need to return an Int from a method then it's signature should end with `-> Int`. That's the syntax ! Can't change it.

[connor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754604/connor) has provided the right piece of code you need.